# Why can Parse Cloud Code run in index.js on Parse Server?

Tags: parse-server, parse-cloud-code

https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/issues/3253

This works for me. But where does Parse comes from while it is not declared in the index.js?

Answer (score 0):

It is in the node_modules under parse. When you do a npm install it will automatically be installed.

Answer (score 0):

parse-server adds Parse to the `global` namespace in node, which is like the global `window` in a browser. That’s why it works without requiring it.